# Extracting parameter id with react-router-dom and useParams

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-dom

I'm trying to extract a parameter from the url and save it as a redux-variable using useParams. So what I'm trying to is the following:

1. I'm opening a restaurant profile with the id of the restaurant via the url.
2. I'm routing to the getRestaurantID-component and extracting the id and calling this.props.setRestaurantId(id) with stores the id as a redux-variable.

My problem is that the function this.props.setRestaurantId(id) is not defined and I really don't know why. Do you have any suggestions?

[image: This is the error I'm getting]

And this is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link, useRouteMatch, useParams} from "react-router-dom";
import HomeComponent from '../components/pages/home';
import AboutComponent from '../components/pages/about';
import RestaurantComponent from '../components/pages/restaurantProfile/restaurant';
import RestaurantList from "../components/pages/restaurantList";
import GetRestaurantId from "./getRestarauntID";



function router(){
    return (
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/about">
                        <About/>
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/restaurant/:id" children={<GetRestaurantId/>}/>
                    <Route path="/restaurants">
                        <Restaurants/>
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/impressum">
                        <Impressum/>
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/">
                        <Home/>
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        );
    }

function Home() {
    return <HomeComponent/>
}

function About() {
    return <AboutComponent/>;
}

function Restaurants(){
    return <RestaurantList/>;
}

function Impressum(){
    return <h2>Impressum</h2>
}


export default router;




import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link, useRouteMatch, useParams} from "react-router-dom";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import Restaurant from "../components/pages/restaurantProfile/restaurant";

function GetId() {

    const { id } = useParams();
    console.log(id);
    this.props.setRestaurantId(id);

    return(
        <div>
            <Restaurant/>
        </div>
    )
}

const  mapDispatchToProps=(dispatch)=>{
    return {
        setRestaurantId: (data) => dispatch({type:'SET_RESTAURANT_ID', payload:data}),
    }
};


export default connect(null,mapDispatchToProps)(GetId);
```

[image: Update]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `this.props` in a functional component.

You can access to the props from the function param directly.

```js
function GetId({setRestaurantId}) {

    const { id } = useParams();
    console.log(id);
    setRestaurantId(id);

    return(
        <div>
            <Restaurant/>
        </div>
    )
}

const  mapDispatchToProps=(dispatch)=>{
    return {
        setRestaurantId: (data) => dispatch({type:'SET_RESTAURANT_ID', payload:data}),
    }
};


export default connect(null,mapDispatchToProps)(GetId);
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I'm not sure if I got this right but if I use your code, the setRestaurantId-function inside mapDispatchToProps is not used.

Comment: I don't understand your message

Comment: You can't access your props ? Can you console.log the props inside the GetId component

Comment: I can't call the setRestaurantId function of mapDispatchToProps. It says that it's not used the way you have described it.

Comment: I put in a screenshot. I copied your code.

Comment: I'm sorry I found my error. Your code worked great! Thank you